# DeepLabV3 MLMultiArray output conversion to Image is super slow

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, ciimage, mlmodel

I'm using the DeepLabV3 `MLModel` provided by Apple from this link: https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/models/.

Seems like the actual prediction is quick. I'm running it on a stream of `CIImage`s which I convert to `CVPixelBuffer`s (quickly).
After performing the prediction I need to get the actual segmentation mask as `CIImage`.
This operation runs super slow even on my iPhone 13 Pro.

Code:

```
let prediction = try! deepLab.prediction(image: pixelBuffer)
let semanticPredictions = prediction.semanticPredictions
```

Two methods I tried to fetch back `CIImage` of the segmentation mask, both super slow:

- Using `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`

  ```
  func fetchMasKUsingGraphicRenderer(mlMultiArray: MLMultiArray) -> CIImage {

    let aWidth = CGFloat(mlMultiArray.shape[0].intValue)
    let aHeight = CGFloat(mlMultiArray.shape[1].intValue)

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: aWidth, height: aHeight))

    let img = renderer.image(actions: { context in
        let ctx = context.cgContext
        ctx.clear(CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: Double(aWidth), height: Double(aHeight)));
        for j in 0..<Int(aHeight) {
            for i in 0..<Int(aWidth) {

                let aValue =
                    (mlMultiArray[j * Int(aHeight) + i].floatValue > 0.0) ?
                        1.0 : 0.0
                let aRect = CGRect(
                    x: CGFloat(i),
                    y: CGFloat(j),
                    width: 1.0,
                    height: 1.0)

                let aColor: UIColor = UIColor(
                    displayP3Red: 0.0,
                    green: 0.0,
                    blue: 0.0,
                    alpha: CGFloat(aValue))

                aColor.setFill()
                UIRectFill(aRect)
            }
        }
    })

    return CIImage(image: img)!
  }
  ```
- Using CoreMLHelpers by Hollance: https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers:

  ```
  let maskedCiImage = CIImage(cgImage: semanticPredictions.cgImage()!)
  ```

**What would be the right way to do it? Thanks!**